# How do I prepare or compile a third party library cloned from github so I can reference it in my program?

Tags: c, libraries, libcurl

I am trying to use a third party library in my C program, in this particular case the library is curl.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Root
    -curl
    -main.c
```

The curl folder the cloned Curl repo from github.

My main.c file has the appropriate header file included, as mentioned in curl docs.

How do I compile, link or prepare the curl folder that I cloned so I can use it in my project?

Comment: How about the [documentation](https://ec.haxx.se/sourcecode/building/building-source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the curl documentation to compile curl into a static or shared library.

If you install the compiled curl library into your system, then you just compile your main program and link against curl: -lcurl. Your compiler will find curl installed In the system, and also find the include folder In the system automatically.

If you *didnt* want to install curl into the system, then install it into your projects directory under a "deps/curl" then link against the file in that local folder, and add the include folder path when compiling. For example, linking against the static lib in your local application folder.

```
gcc -o app -I ./deps/curl/include -l ./deps/curl/lib/curl.a
```

Comment: gcc main.c -lcurl, super easy. This is called linking? So can just homebrew the C libraries and then -l*packagename* and the magic workds, as long as header files are correct?

Comment: Correct. Linking is the process of bringing together separate pieces of code. Yes, Compile and install the library into the system, then you can just -lLibraryName. If the library is called "libcurl.so", you would use:  -lcurl.  (you drop the "lib" part).